# Which variables are allowed in a __str__ implementation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python `@property` annotation using [this](https://www.online-python.com/online_python_compiler). My understanding is that it is a built-in property to facilitate accessing and modifying class properties. I created a class using this annotation on some properties, then tried implementing str to display everything.

Below, everything displays fine using the `str()` method. However, when I substitute `self._area` for `self.area`, I get `AttributeError: Circle object has no attribute _area`

In the `str()` implementation, why am I allowed to use `self._diameter` but ***not*** self._area?

```
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius): 
        self._radius=radius
    
    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius
        
    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        self._radius=radius
    
    @property 
    def diameter(self):
        return self._diameter
    
    @diameter.setter
    def diameter(self, diameter):
        self._diameter=diameter
    
    @diameter.deleter
    def diameter(self):
        del self._diameter
    
    @property
    def area(self):
        self._area = self._radius**2*3.14
        return self._area

        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Circle has radius of {self._radius}, diameter of {self._diameter}, and area of {self.area}'    
        
c = Circle(4)
c.diameter=3
print(str(c))
```

Comment: `self._area` is undefined until `self.area` is accessed. But you don't need it you can just `return self._radius**2*3.14`.

Comment: `self._diameter` exists because you set in when you called `c.diameter=3`. `self._area` doesn't exist because you've never accessed the `self.area` property, sot that code has never run. If you were just to refer to the properties in your `__str__` implementation you wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: If you're using no-op properties that fully implement getting, setting and deleting, drop them entirely, and just use an attribute; this isn't C++/Java where getters and setters provide useful future-proofing by maintaining API compatibility or the like, if you ever need a property, you can replace the attribute with a property seamlessly, but when the property isn't helping you, just use the raw attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because you (rather pointlessly) compute `self._area` lazily, only when `self.area` is accessed. So your `__str__` implementation will work just fine if the user accesses `c.area` ahead of time, but doesn't work when it hasn't been accessed.

Simple solution: Use an eagerly computed attribute or a lazily computed property, don't mix the two in confusing ways. As a rule, you should define (even if it's just with `None` for lazily computed attributes) *all* attributes in `__init__`; it's maintainer-friendly (they don't have to search the whole class to figure out the set of attributes) and modern CPython rewards you for it (by using key-sharing dictionaries for attribute storage, reducing the per-instance memory overhead by a significant amount, very roughly halving memory overhead).

---

As an aside, properties that provide full access to the underlying attribute are pointless in Python; if you're giving the user full access anyway, just make it a regular attribute, saving a bunch of boilerplate and making the code run faster. This is the case with both `radius` and `diameter` in your code. In the case of `diameter` though, having it manage a separate attribute makes no sense (`diameter` is definitionally twice the radius, so they should use common state, `_diameter` should never exist), and `area` is cheap enough to recompute that it should probably just be an uncached property.

A simplified, idiomatic version of your class would look like:

```
class Circle:  # (object) only necessary on Py2; hope you're not developing for it
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius  # Use a public attribute without bothering with
                              # pointless property wrapping that protects nothing
                              # and just slows things down

    # diameter is just another "view" of the radius, so make the property
    # perform converting mutations to the radius
    @property
    def diameter(self):
        return self.radius * 2  # Computable from radius

    @diameter.setter
    def diameter(self, diameter):
        self.radius = diameter / 2  # Convert to radius and store

    @property
    def area(self):
        # This is cheap enough to compute that it's probably not worth
        # caching (if the radius changes, you'd have to invalidate/recompute the cached value, it's just a pain)
        return math.pi * self.radius ** 2  # Computable from radius

    def __str__(self):
        # Use the accessors; they're accurate, and duplicating the code to compute
        # them is silly
        return f'Circle has radius of {self.radius}, diameter of {self.diameter}, and area of {self.area}'


c = Circle(4)
c.diameter = 3
print(c)  # print already stringifies; calling str on it is redundant
```

Side-note: You always want to implement `__repr__` on a class, just so tracebacks and the like referencing it are useful; it's pretty easy to write (using `type(self).__name__` makes it subclass friendly when the `__init__` arguments don't change):

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'{type(self).__name__}({self._radius!r})'  # !r meaningless for int/float, but it's good to use it as a habit for when it matters, e.g. str arguments
```

Comment: an idiomatic form of this class would not have a `radius` `property`, but if it should, it should use `self.radius = radius` in `__init__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Ah, right. I even said not to use redundant properties, then forgot to fix that part. Fixed.

Comment: @larsks re: "...If you were just to refer to the properties in your __str__ implementation you wouldn't have this issue." If i understand what you're saying, that is exactly what I tried to do but it threw the ae.

Comment: @chocalaca: You said you got the error when you referred to `self._area` (the *attribute*), but not when you referred to `self.area` (the *property*). The property worked (in a slightly silly way, but it worked), the attribute did not work before the property had been accessed.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yep, understood per the accepted and very clear answer. If this is for my reply to larsks, just making sure I'm not missing his point.